# strfind split keyword within paragraph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

After the output of keywords in URL, how do I check whether the keywords exist in the content of the page like the content below, if yes then return 1, else return 0. There is strfind at there, but I do not have idea why it cannot work

```
str = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname'
Paragraph = 'hostname From wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Jump to: navigation, search In    computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename .....'
SplitStrings = regexp(str,'[/.]','split')

for it = SplitStrings
c( it{1} ) = strfind(Paragraph, it{1} )
end

SplitStrings = {};

feature11=(cellfun(@(n) isempty(n), strfind(Paragraph, SplitStrings{1})))
```

[image]

I can do with the below code 4 checking whether 'https' exist or not. But, how to modify the 'SplitString' into 'B6'?

```
str = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname'

A6 = regexp(str,'\w*://','match','once')
B6 = {'https'};

feature6=(cellfun(@(n) isempty(n), strfind(A6, B6{1})))
```

Comment: Remove the `{1}` and try again.

Comment: both '{1}'? but it show me an error:

??? Error using ==> cell.strfind at 35
If any of the input arguments are cell arrays, the first must be
a cell array of strings and the second must be a character array.

Error in ==> f11 at 12
c( it ) = strfind(data1, it )

Comment: Ok, then my guess was wrong. What exactly is the problem? In what way is it not working?

Comment: I could not detect the 'wikipedia' word which exist in the 'paragraph'then will return 0, then 'hostname' does not exist in the 'paragraph' then will return 1....

Comment: [https en wikipedia org wiki hostname]=[0 0 1 0 0]

Comment: I don't understand... `Hostname` is in there, right at the start of `Paragraph`. If you want to find `wikipedia`, you should use `lower(Paragraph)` and `lower(it{1})`, `strfind` searches in case sensitive mode.

Comment: ops, sorry...[https en wikipedia org wiki hostname]=[0 0 1 0 1]

Comment: thx 4 remind, but it stil could not work, i get the output as below...any idea?
c = 

  containers.Map handle
  Package: containers

  Properties:
        Count: 1
      KeyType: 'char'
    ValueType: 'any'

  Methods, Events, Superclasses

Comment: Is your intended output a logical array? I don't see why you're using `containers.Map`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I want to try with different way, just a testing, can ignore it. I have edited the above question 4, plz have a look =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely not clear to me what you want to do here...

I suspect it is this:

```
str      = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname';

haystack = 'hostname From wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Jump to: navigation, search In    computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename .....';
needles  = regexp(str,'[:/.]*','split') %// note the different search string

%// What I think you want to do
~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(haystack, needles, 'once'))
```

Results:

```
needles = 
    'http'    'en'    'wikipedia'    'org'    'wiki'    'hostname'
ans =
     0     1     1     0     1     1
```

but if this is not the case, please edit your question and include your desired outputs for some example inputs.

**EDIT**

OK, so if I understand you corretly now, you want *whole words* and not partial matches. You must tell this to `regexp`, in the following way:

```
%// NOTE: these  metacharacters indicate that match is to occur 
%//       at beginning AND end of word (so whole words only)
needles  = strcat('\<', regexpi(str,'[:/.]*','split'), '\>') 

%// Search for these words in the paragraph
~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(haystack, needles, 'once'))
```

Comment: yes, that is what I want, but the 'en' return me 1, although 'encyclopedia' contain the 'en', but i want if the str contain 'encyclopedia' only return 1, if 'en' then return 0

Comment: why do I cannot replace "str      = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname';" with "str = importdata('URL')" ? because I have a lots of URL that need to be import from note pad instead of showing str1, str2....in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
f=@(str) isempty(strfind(Paragraph,str))
cellfun(f,SplitStrings)
```

This should get whole words. The key is parsing the variable Paragraph to get them

```
SplitParagraph=regexp(Paragraph,'[ ,:.()]','split');
I=ismember(SplitStrings,SplitParagraph);
SplitStrings(I)
```

Comment: yes, that is what I want, but the 'en' return me 1, although 'encyclopedia' contain the 'en', but i want if the str contain 'encyclopedia' only return 1, if 'en' then return 0